# Generation 1 AirPods only playing audio while inside charging case

Tags: audio, airpods

I lost my AirPods (generation 1) charging case 6 months back, so I now have the new wireless charging case.

I keep my AirPods inside the new charging case but now have a problem - if I take the AirPods out of the charging case, the sound of the music I'm playing on my iPhone doesn't come through. If I put the AirPods back in the charging case, the sound then starts coming through again.

Can someone advise how I might approach trying to fix this issue?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!

Comment: 1. Did you reset the AirPods to work with the new case by holding the button on the case for 15+ seconds? 2. Is the sound coming out of your phone? It sounds like the AirPods may be connecting automatically to your phone (as intended), so the sound is coming out of the AirPods? 3. Please clarify where sound is coming from and what you believe should be different.

Comment: I just bought a replacement charging case for my year-old AirPods (Gen. 1) and they exhibit the same symptoms: I can play music through them while in the case, but as soon as I remove them, the connection fails. I suspect battery failure because they were at 0% for so long.